# Using SendKeys in OS X with HP UFT

Tags: macos, vbscript, safari, qtp, hp-uft

I am trying to run my automated scripts remotely on Mac using HP UFT 12.02 and one of my test cases is to use the SendKeys method by doing the following:

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.SendKeys()
```

I understand the above code won't work as `WshShell` is designed to run locally. The best alternative I can think of is to use AppleScript to help my send keystrokes but HP UFT doesn't support that language.

Is there any way I can send keystrokes remotely to the Mac using VBScript or by using one of the built-in methods of HP UFT?

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I can think of is to connect to the Mac via some sort of [remote control](http://www.tightvnc.com/) software and then have UFT work on the client side (and allow it to simulate the key input on the Mac).

You can probably use [Insight (image based automation)](http://community.hpe.com/t5/All-About-the-Apps/A-guide-to-Image-Based-Testing-with-HP-UFT-s-Insight/ba-p/6355855) in order to direct the events to the correct object inside the remote control client.

Comment: @Stephen, as far as I know you cannot. Perhaps if there's an application that simulates the keyboard you can use it via `RemoteConnection.Run` to execute it. A short search found this: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/136695/how-to-use-terminal-to-send-keystrokes

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I did explore the option of using AppleScript to simulate a key press. Unfortunately, `RemoteConnection.Run` only supports Safari at the moment. Thus, it's not possible to launch Terminal to execute the script.

Comment: @Stephen, are you sure? I thought you could run any OSX application.

Comment: Yup. From the documentation of `RemoteConnect.Run` method: _Runs an application on a remote computer. Currently, this method can be used only to run the Safari browser on a remote Mac computer._

Comment: @Stephen bummer :( please double check since documentation is sometimes wrong.